# Compare columns of 2 matrices to determine the column values in one matrix that should be paired with the other matrix

Tags: r

I have matrix M and N given by

```
> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    5    1    1    7    7
[2,]    4    7    4    2    7
[3,]   11   19   20   50   30

> N
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    7    1
[2,]    7    7
```

I want to find the column values in M that should be paired with N to get

```
  [,1] [,2]
    7    1
    7    7
    30   19
```

I tried the code below. Can i get an efficient way of doing it or especially doing it without using the for commands?

```
E=numeric()
for (i in 1:2){
    for (j in 1:5) {
        if (N[1,i]==M[1,j] & N[2,i]==M[2,j]){
           E[i]= M[3,j]
        }
    }  
}
E
rbind(N,E)
```

Comment: what is `vect`?

Comment: @nate.edwinton I have edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here is your loop re-written

```
E <- vapply(seq(nrow(N)), function(i) M[3,M[1,] == N[1,i] & M[2,] == N[2,i]], numeric(1))
# with
> rbind(N,E)
  [,1] [,2]
     7    1
     7    7
E   30   19
```

there is only one loop (`vapply` - a wrapper for a loop) which runs through the rows of `N`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using multiple calls to `apply`. We iterate over the columns of `M` and `N` to find which column in `M` matches the first column in `N` and then which matches the second column in `N`.

```
logicals <- apply(M[-3,], # exclude third row
                  2, # iterate over columns
                  FUN = function(x) 
                    apply(N, 2, #then iterate over columns of N
                          FUN = function(y) all(x == y)))

#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
# [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  

M[,apply(logicals, 1, which)]

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    7    1
[2,]    7    7
[3,]   30   19
```

#### data

```
M <- structure(c(5, 4, 11, 1, 7, 19, 
        1, 4, 20, 7, 2, 50, 
        7, 7, 30), 
      .Dim = c(3L, 5L))

N <- structure(c(7, 7, 1, 7), .Dim = c(2L, 2L))
```